# I want Technology Box will be shown in Dropdown in Create

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want my technology text box will be show in dropdown but classes are different PROJECT IS one Class and Technology is another class like

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string? ProjectName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime? End { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? ProjectHead { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Status { get; set; }

        public string? Technology { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProjectTechnology>? ProjectTechnology { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
    {
        public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
        public string? TechnologyName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProjectTechnology>? ProjectTechnology { get; set; }
    }

public class ProjectTechnology
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int TechnologyId { get; set; }

        public Project? Project { get; set; }
        public Technology? Technology { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Css html Page it will create using scaffolding i want this will be shown in dropdown get data from database in technology field.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="Technology" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Technology" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Technology" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you  pass the Project model to   Css html Page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Project.cs:

```
public class Project
        {
            public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    
            [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
            [Required]
            public string? ProjectName { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string? Description { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string? ProjectHead { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string? Status { get; set; }
    
            
           public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
           public Technology Technology{ get; set; } 

            
    }
```

Technology.cs

```
public class Technology
    {
        public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
        public string? TechnologyName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Project>? Project { get; set; }
    }
```

In Program.cs,add code like below:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
```

In appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbContext": "Filename= C:\\Users\\Administrator\\sqlite\\ITProjectDB.db"
  }
```

MyDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Technology> Technology { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Project { get; set; }

       
    }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: it will show error  sqlite constraint failed

Comment: You don't use SQLSever?

Comment: No i use sqlite because i have mac

Comment: @gouravkumar please see my update answer. Check with your sqlite setting ,my demo is work.